# ROS_DISTRO set to hydro after indigo install

Tags: ros, installation, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In Linux, my .bashrc had only one line pertaining to ROS:

`source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash`

Yet I was getting the following error message upon opening a new shell:

`ROS_DISTRO was set to 'hydro' before. Please make sure that the environment does not mix paths from different distributions.`

It turns out that due to some shell caching or something, ROS_DISTRO was stuck on 'hydro' even after removing the source line from the .bashrc. This problem was solved by simply logging out and back in.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/168311/ros_distro-set-to-hydro-after-indigo-install/) by [wayne](https://answers.ros.org/users/18281/wayne/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2014-05-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Log out and back in.

---

Originally posted by [wayne](https://answers.ros.org/users/18281/wayne/) with karma: 26 on 2014-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's not always obvious, but your terminals inherit their environment from your X session. I suspect you had ROS sourced in your X session, before the shell started.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2